# How to make list items round after they are revealed with staggered animation with Framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I have a staggered animation for list items that must be revealed one after the other nice and slow with framer motion.

[Items revealed with staggered animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoI7T.png)

But once they are revealed with this animation I need to change the border radius of all items
[Rounded corners after staggered animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXYF0.jpg)

Is that possible with framer motion? How can I get the animation end state of staggered animation and apply the radius once it's done?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

With "initial" and "animation" the radius starts to get applied to each item during the revealing animation but I need all list items to be revealed with staggered animation with no radius and once all are visible then only apply radius

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Please  open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the end of an animation with Framer Motion's [`onAnimationComplete`](https://www.framer.com/motion/component/###onanimationcomplete) prop. Once the animation completes, you can set some state that the animation has completed and animate the children accordingly. Here is an example:

```
function App() {
  const [animationComplete, setAnimationComplete] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="w-full min-h-screen flex justify-center items-center bg-zinc-800">
      <motion.div
        variants={container}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="show"
        className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-5"
        // onAnimationComplete added to the parent of the staggered animations
        onAnimationComplete={() => setAnimationComplete(true)}
      >
        {sqaures.map((_, index) => (
          <motion.div
            key={index}
            variants={item}
            animate={animationComplete && borderRadiusRules[index]}
            className="w-[100px] h-[100px] bg-green-400"
          ></motion.div>
        ))}
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see a [working example here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/competent-framework-ylx7r6?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpmt93wb0006356hhglrkhrv%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpmt93wa0002356hw7i64jin%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpmt93wa0004356hymnf8s04%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpmt93wa0005356hqzi57ah8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60%252C40%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpmt93wa0002356hw7i64jin%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpmt93w90001356hsn05z9ae%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpmt93wa0002356hw7i64jin%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpmt93w90001356hsn05z9ae%2522%257D%252C%2522clpmt93wa0005356hqzi57ah8%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpmt93wa0005356hqzi57ah8%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpmtiegy00rv356h7qhpop7a%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpmtiegy00rv356h7qhpop7a%2522%257D%252C%2522clpmt93wa0004356hymnf8s04%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpmt93wa0004356hymnf8s04%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpmtaw9300gz356honm3ruzf%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpmtaw9300gz356honm3ruzf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer Rico.

Comment: No worries. If you found it helpful, feel free to [mark it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)